# Find more than one elements in struct vector at the same time

Tags: c++, struct

I have a struct like

```
struct Event {
    std::string name;
    int date;
    int number;
    int event;
};
```

Next a parse a text file which has three columns separated with ":" using  ifstream  like

```
while (getline(EventsFile, line))
    {
        std::vector<std::string> columns = split(line,':');
        Event events_;

        events_.name     = "Test";
        events_.date     = std::stoi(columns[0]);
        events_.number   = std::stoi(columns[1]);
        events_.event = std::stof(columns[2]);

        EventList.push_back(events_);
    }
```

so far, so good- Next, I need to cross-check against another list if a record A:B:C exists - The simplest way is to do like (info1,info2,info3 is the columns from the second text file again parsed with ifstream but this is simple enough so I dont post details)

```
for (const Event & m: EventList)
        {
        if (m.date == info1 && m.number==info2 && m.event == info3)
        cout<<"=========================================== >>>>>>>>>>>>  "<<m.name<<"  "<<m.run<<"  "<<m.lumi<<"  "<<m.eventrn<<endl;
        }
```

This is a very slow process, so I tried to make a new struct which will return a bool if A==info1 && B=info2 && C=info3 like

```
struct find_element
{
    int run;
    int date;
    int event;
    find_element(int run,int date,int event) : run(run),date(date),event(event) {}
    bool operator () ( const int& a , const int &b, const int &c)
    {
        if (run==a.run && date==b.date && event == c.event)
        return true;
    }
};
```

But this does not work...any help ?

Comment: Linked lists tend to be slow and should be avoided unless you need to insert/remove before the end. A vector would probably be faster, but wouldn't remove the fact you are performing a linear search for every element. You could store the elements in a `std::map` with an appropriate key, which would be more efficient, or a sorted vector and perform a binary search.

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Your `operator()` isn't right. It never returns false. (You should be getting a compiler warning about this.) Instead of an `if` just return the bool expression `return run==a.run && date==b.date && event == c.event;` I assume you're using this with `std::find_if`?

Comment: What I get is like
`error: request for member 'run' in 'a', which is of non-class type 'const int'`
and the same for the other defined parameters as well